# Is there any DOM Event triggered on PWA browser app uninstall?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm showing a custom installation dialog to install the PWA app using the **beforeinstallprompt** event.
This event is not fired when the app is installed only on desktops. But on Android device, the event is fired even after installing the app because its not installed as a APK as per the [doc](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/installation-prompt#the_beforeinstallprompt_event)

I fixed this using local storage to track if the app is installed and this works fine on both desktop and android devices.

```
 window.addEventListener('appinstalled', () => {
    localStorage.setItem('app-installed', 'true')
  })
```

**Issue:** There is no event triggered when the app is uninstalled/removed on android device and the local storage data is also not cleared.
App is not listed in app list (settings -> apps)  to clear the data before uninstalling.
Therefore, its not possible to show the install dialog again after uninstalling the app.

Is there any DOM event triggered on app uninstall to clear/ reset the local storage?